# How to improve this piece of sed to search and replace

Tags: regex, sed

I cannot find how to improve the sed command below in order to take care of the following three file name patterns.

*Name of document*

*P1932_Name of document*

*1932 Name of document*

As it is now, it outputs correctly the replacement for the first two examples: *"Name of document"*. For the third example, it adds an unwanted space in front of the name: *" Name of document"* (there is a space in front of *Name*).

`sed -E 's/^[P]{0,1}[0-9]{0,4}[_\s]{0,2}(.*$)/\\1/g'`

Comment: If `1932 Name of document` is not the expected output, can you clarify what is?

Comment: The problem is in the replacement. The replacement for the third example has a space before the name of the file, whilst the other two rightly don't.

Comment: I have modified the description of the problem to clarify that it is in the replacement for the third example.

Comment: I think you could clarify further. Can you please provide an example of the three inputs and three desired outputs?

Comment: Try `echo "P1932_Name of document" | sed -E 's/^[P]{0,1}[0-9]{0,4}[_\s]{0,2}(.*?)$/\1/g'`, again, your question is a bit unclear.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, @UnbearableLightness. I have modified the description of the problem to include the outputs. I have also added your suggestion to include the start of string. However, the problem remains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ sed -E 's/^P{0,1}[0-9]{0,4}[_[:space:]]{0,2}//' file
Name of document
Name of document
Name of document
```

You can use `\s` as shorthand for `[[:space:]]` (i.e. the character class `[:space:]` inside a bracket expression `[...]`) in GNU sed, but `\s` **inside** a bracket expression `[\s]` is just the literal characters `\` and `s`. IMHO in sed you should always just use the character classes to avoid any confusion. So to be clear:

- `\s` = `[[:space:]]`
- `[\s]` = `\` or `s`

Comment: After writing the character class for space in full, it does work. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. Hopefully you realize that with all those RE intervals starting at 0 your command would turn a title like `Pirates` into `irates` and otherwise mess with presumably valid titles (it'd turn the title `1984` into a null string), your regexp would match more than just the target substrings in your example. So you may want to put some thought into a more restrictive regexp that ONLY matches the prefixes you want removed.